# sql find not matching records

Tags: sql-server-2008

Two tables.
I have column a (datetime type) and column b (numeric type) in both tables.
I want to search column a in both tables and get ONLY the non matching ones.
Then display only the column a and b that do not have a matching datetime column a.

```
    Select Column b from Table 1 
    left join Table 2
    where Table1.Column a <> Table2.Column a
```

Is this correct??

Comment: No, it's not correct.  You're not indicating what to join on.  Among other errors.

Comment: In the first part, are you trying to get the different values of a for  each value of b? or just trying to do a union?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a left join as indicated by @drjay or a `NOT IN` clause. Personally I prefer the NOT in as it is easier to read.

```
SELECT [Column b] 
FROM [Table 1]
WHERE [Column a] NOT IN (
    SELECT [Column a]
    FROM [Table 2]
)
```

Comment: no problems, if the answer worked mark it as the chosen answer (the green tick beside this answer)

Answer (score 1):

You are close. Not sure of the exact syntax because I don't have SQL Server. But in MySQL it is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_1 t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.date = t2.date 
WHERE t1.date <> t2.date;
```

The logic for your question should be similar. Just change the syntax if necessary.